# How to get csv file object from zipobject in jszip and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, jszip

I am trying to get csv file object from zipobject which i extracted from a zip file using jszip.But Now i am not able to read the actual csv file from this zipobject.Can anybody help?
this is my zipobject,[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jszip@2.4.0" data-semver="2.4.0" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Stuk/jszip/v2.4.0/dist/jszip.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="testController">


  <div>
    <input type="file" name="archiveUpload" id="archiveUpload01">
  </div>

  <script>
    angular
      .module('myApp', [])
      .run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.title = 'myTest Page';
      })
      .controller('testController', ['$scope', '$q',
        function($scope, $q) {

          $scope.extractArchive = function(zipfile) {
            var dfd = $q.defer();
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onerror = dfd.reject.bind(dfd);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
              if (!reader.result) dfd.reject(new Error("Unknown error"));

              var zip = new JSZip(reader.result);
              return dfd.resolve(zip);
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(zipfile);
            return dfd.promise;
          }

          function onArchiveChange(evt) {
            var target = evt.dataTransfer || evt.target;
            var file = target && target.files && target.files[0];
            $scope.extractArchive(file)
              .then(function(zipFile) {
                console.log(zipFile)
              })
          }

          angular.element(document.querySelector('#archiveUpload01')).on('change', onArchiveChange);


        }
      ])
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`async`](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_zipobject/async.html) method to get a promise of the content (which behave like  [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)):

```
zip.file("Positions.csv").async("text")
.then(function success(txt) {
  console.log("csv is", txt);
}, function error(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

**Edit**: the code above is for JSZip v3, you use JSZip v2:

```
var txt = zip.file("Positions.csv").asText();
console.log("csv is", txt);
```

`zip.file("Positions.csv")` will give you the ZipObject you show on your image.

**Edit 2**: `extractArchive`, written for JSZip v3, looks like:

```
$scope.extractArchive = function(zipfile) {
  return JSZip.loadAsync(zipfile); // JSZip v3 can read Blobs and Files
}; // returns a promise of a JSZip instance
```

You can then chain other promises:

```
$scope.extractArchive(zipfile).then(function (zip) {
  return zip.file("Positions.csv").async("arraybuffer");
}).then(function (buf) {
  var blob = new Blob([buf]);
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where does the `zip` came from?

Comment: What do you mean in file format ? As a Blob, ready for `saveAs` ? That would be `var buf = zip.file(...).asArrayBuffer(); var blob = new Blob([buf]);` See [the old documentation](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/blob/v2.6.1/documentation/api_zipobject.md) for available getters. I also updated my answer for the JSZip version you use.

Comment: how to use JSZip version 3.1.3 to load a zip file to read its contents? Everytime i use `JSZip.loadAsync ` returns error .

Comment: I edited my answer. If you still have issues with `JSZip.loadAsync`, you should open an other question to keep things readable for others.